# Run shell script on windows using Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, shell-script

I am having trouble with running .sh script on Windows using Cygwin.

When i run the file: `./build.sh -s srv.txt`
I am getting: `./build.sh: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory`

Can you guys help me what does that mean. The 1st line is commented :)

thanks.

Comment: Is bash in `/bin`? Is it executable (chmod +x /bin/bash)?

Comment: I did it, yeah which bash is giving `/usr/bin/bash`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue running cygwin under windows. For me, it had nothing to do with the path.

It had everything to do with the encoding. I was using `UTF-8` with the [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). The BOM was causing it to choke. Once I removed it, it worked flawlessly.

I updated the encoding using Notepad++ by:

> Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 without BOM

The `which bash` command outputted:

```
/usr/bin/bash
```

However it was still able to resolve

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5):

It usually means there's a `^M` (carriage return) at the end of each line of your file or some other encoding issue which prevents the `#!/bin/bash` line being interpreted correctly.

Take a copy of the file and save it as plain ASCII using an editor of your choice to remove as much non-ASCII encoding as possible.  Also, try to save it in 'UNIX' format if the editor supports it.

Comment: What is vim? I have notepad++, I am on windows.

Comment: vim is a unix file editor, if the file won't run under Cygwin, the best bet is find out why under Cygwin.  The problem is you're saving a windows file (which has carriage returns *and* linefeeds) and trying to run it under Cygwin.  If you can, tell Notepad++ to save in 'unix' format.

Comment: I did it, There is an option to make it UNIX format and I did it using notepad++

Comment: Can you at least try what I suggest?  Edit it in vim (in your Cygwin shell type, vim build.sh), and then type what I said, and see if the ^M symbols show up at the end of each line.

Comment: Should I install vim for this? Getting: `-bash: vim: command not found
`

Comment: It's part Cygwin, but I guess you don't have it installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6042/discussion-between-eightbittony-and-elbek)

Comment: Installed vim, I opened the file with vim, I do not see any ^M. But Cygwin says vim is not found

Comment: Chat doesn't seem to be logging me in, what does this command (in cygwin) return, `file build.sh`

Comment: Getting : `build.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text executable`

Comment: The BOM is probably the issue. UTF-8 doesn't need a BOM anyway. See if you can save it without the BOM in your editor (maybe it offers a plain ASCII encoding), or else use a different editor.

Comment: Use this to see if you have the proper line endings:  <pre>od -c</pre>  This command shows exactly what characters are present.

Comment: Since you have Cygwin, you can also convert the line endings with the `dos2unix` utility.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to run...

```
sh build.sh
```

Instead of...

```
./build.sh
```

I'm not sure (I never ran Cygwin) but it seems that `/bin/bash` is not a path in your machine, so your shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) blows the program.

If you run the program using `sh` the shebang should be treated as a comment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`#!/bin/bash` (called a shebang, short for Crash (`#`) Bang (`!`), tells the shell which program to use to execute the script in question.  You'll see this with perl scripts (`#!/usr/bin/perl`), Python (`#!/usr/bin/python`), or php (`#!/usr/bin/php`) as well.

In your situation, a few things could be causing it.  Either the 'bash' shell is not installed or the script is in an unrecognized format that you can't see.

First, does bash exist?  Give us the results of this:  `ls -l /bin/bash`

Second, what is in the script?  Give us the first 2 lines of this:  `od -c build.sh`  What we're looking for is the script being in the wrong format.  Windows likes `CRLF'`or `\r\n` for a line ending while Linux only likes `LF` or `\n` (see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

To be honest, I don't know if CYGWIN likes Windows line endings or Linux, but that's a very likely cause for your issue.

Again, give us the output of `od -c build.sh` and we'll see what's up.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have had /M problems in python scripts written on a windows box and trying to use them on a linux box.  I used dos2unix to convert the files to make them operable on the linux box.
If carriage returns (or other windows text formatting issues) exist and are the cause of the problem this might help.